# Vue 3 Select-Option, make first option the default

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make the first select option default, therefore showing right away when the page loads. I thought since `v-bind:selected` is a booleanish attribute I could just use something simple like `index === 0` to select the first by default but this doesn't seem to be working, and there is no option selected on page load. I've debugged and the indexes are incrementing normally, there's nothing weird going on there. Is there just something silly I'm missing maybe? `selectedThingId` is a ref with a default value of zero. I've also looked in the html changing this number and nothing is ever selected!

Here's the template code:

```
<select name="select" id="select" v-model="selectedThingId" @change="onChangeFunction">
    <option v-for="(thing, index) in things"
        :value="thing.id"
        :key="thing.id"
        :selected="index === 0"
    >
        {{ thing }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `selectedThingId` in `onMounted` hook :

```js
const { ref, reactive, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const selectedThingId = ref(null)
    const things = reactive([{id: 3, name: 'aaa'}, {id: 5, name: 'bbb'}, {id: 9, name: 'ccc'}])
    
    onMounted(() => selectedThingId.value = things[0].id)
    
    const onChangeFunction =() => {}
    return { things, selectedThingId, onChangeFunction }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select name="select" id="select" v-model="selectedThingId" @change="onChangeFunction">
    <option v-for="(thing, index) in things" :key="thing.id"
      :value="thing.id"
    >
      {{ thing.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  {{ selectedThingId }}
</div>
```